# Luigi dealing with missing tasks with mutiple dependency tasks

Tags: python, luigi

Lets say i have about 5 tasks for 5 different period, outputting one excel file each. I will then need to merge these 5 output files in a new task, but one of the tasks has not been completed, but i still want the rest of these 4 files to be merged to one single file. Is there a way of doing this in Luigi.
Here is some sample code that might help understand the question

```
class MakeFile():
    period = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        return cleaned_file

class MergeFiles():
    def requires(self):
        periods = #mutiple periods
        for period in periods:
            yield MakeFile(period)

    def run(self):
        #merge files here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you can write nothing to your `output`. Basically, Luigi checks that a task is complete if all the things returned by the `output` method of a task exists. So, you could just open and close the excel files without writing anything and then testing if they are empty in `MergeFiles`.

Beyond that, you have made a couple of mistakes in your current classes.

1. In `MakeFile`, you don't return anything from `run`. You need to create an `output` method and return targets. See https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#task-output for more details.
2. In the `requires` method of `MergeFiles`, you don't `yield` in the requires method. The `yield` function is used when you are running a task and need to dynamically require additional tasks. If that is actually what you need, you can read more here: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies. I think you should just use `return [MakeFile(period) for period in periods]` in your `requires`. Then you can access them in run by using `self.input()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to add the `output` function, and when the question has been able to be solved if i made an empty excel file in `MakeFile`.